# EPPlus How to add LineSeries with specific range of data from worksheet

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I create an Excel file in code. So far, everything works out fine.

[Created excel file (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xokCM.jpg)

I want to create the following chart in code

[Excel with Chart (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOIcU.jpg)
(Notice the selected cells and xseries names)

In Excel its easy.

> But how do I do that in code?

My experiment

```
string values = "='Overall Results'!B3;'Overall Results'!D3;'Overall Results'!F3;'Overall Results'!H3;'Overall Results'!J3";
string xSerie = "='Overall Results'!$B$1:$K$1";

linechart.Series.Add(values, xSerie);
```

didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a string with the EPPlus cell adresses.

```
string values = worksheet.Cells[3, 2].Address + ":" + worksheet.Cells[3, 4].Address + ":" + worksheet.Cells[3, 6].Address;

linechart.Series.Add(values, ExcelRange.GetAddress(1, 2, 1, 11));
```

Comment: With the : you specify a range.
I don't want a contiguous area. I need every second column of a row.

Answer (score 0):

Had this problem aswell, but i found a solution:

For some reason, in order to get multiple specific cells in EPPlus, every cell has to be in a range.

So creating multiple ranges, which each only contains 1 cell, is the way to go

```
string values = "sheetName!B3:sheetName!B3,sheetName!D3:sheetName!D3,sheetName!F3:sheetName!F3,sheetName!H3:sheetName!H3,sheetName!J3:sheetName!J3";

var valueCells = sheet.Cells[values];

string xSerie = (Same concept);

var xCells = sheet.Cells[xSerie];

linechart.Series.Add(valueCells, xCells);
```